# Как в Java заменить (перезаписать) части файла?

Tags: java, файлы, потоки-данных, randomaccessfile

Есть файл, надо в нём найти и заменить определённые части на другие (той же длины).

Я понимаю, что можно построчно читать файл, для прочитанной строки делать замену и записывать её в другой файл, как предлагается [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563294/modifying-existing-file-content-in-java).

Но мне кажется, что это весьма странный подход, т. к. для достаточно больших файлов это, хоть и на короткий промежуток времени, забивает свободную память, которой в теории может и не быть в нужный момент.

Нет ли какого-то способа сделать замену частей ***на месте***?

Например в Си или Python можно сделать что-то подобное:

```
with io.open(file_path, "r+b") as f:
    for line in iter(lambda: fh.readline(), b""):
        if b"pattern" in line:
            newline = re.sub(b"pattern", b"replacement", line)
            f.seek(-len(line), 1)
            f.write(newline)
```

Хотелось бы получить что-то подобное на **Java**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java есть [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). Позволяет писать в произвольное место файла.

С помощью метода `seek` можно пропустить нужное количество байт от начала файла, а с помощью `write` писать байты в середину файла, не меняя при этом другие части файла.

Например, у вас есть файл `input.txt` с содержимым в ASCII-кодировке:

```
Hello world!
```

Предположим, нужно перезаписать второе слово:

```java
File file = new File("input.txt");
try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")) {
    raf.seek(6);
    raf.writeBytes("ololo");
}
```

На выходе получим:

```
Hello ololo!
```